# Blender Smoke Domain Cube casts a shadow

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

This is what I see when I try to render smoke.

[image: This]

The smoke itself renders okay, but there is a problem that the domain cube itself casts a shadow. How do I solve this?

material of the domain object :

[image]

Comment: Can we see the material settings for your domain object?

Comment: [Here. Sorry for the accidental tooltips.](http://imgur.com/a/9dCog)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable *Shadow > Receive Transparent* in the ground plane's material:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is easy: in the material panel for the domain, disable "traceable".

Edit: This works if you don't want any shadow at all. If you want to still have the shadow from the smoke, refer to gandalf3's answer.